# Screen flickering, "burned in", vertical lines of discoloration. Enough to diagnose broken monitor?

Tags: display, operating-systems, nvidia-graphics-card

I own a Lenovo L2264A computer monitor, connected to a Dell XPS 8910 computer, including a Nvidia 750 Ti graphics card (default drivers). I was running Windows 10 as set up by default when the computer was purchased, when about a month ago I decided to install Ubuntu 17. The installation went smoothly and nothing was out of the ordinary. However, about two weeks ago I noticed that I was beginning to get some screen flickering, focused around the edges. At first I didn't think anything of it, seeing that it disappeared after a couple of minutes. However, a few days ago the screen flickering reappeared much worse than before while I was using Discord. In addition, vertical lines appeared on the screen at small intervals (~20 px) each slightly discolored, in a consistent manner (same background color caused same discoloration). Additionally, the screen looked "burned in", i.e. when I switched from Discord to a different window, I could still see some of the Discord window. This issue persisted for about 60 minutes before it fully went away. During this entire time, I could see the same "snapshot" of my Discord screen, even after some of the trouble shooting steps I took below. Also, this was focused around the edges of the screen. I was on Ubuntu when this happened.

I started trouble shooting by restarting my computer. This did not help. All three of the problems I mentioned above persisted. I then switched over to Windows, and the problems persisted anyway. The only thing that seemed to help stop this was time. Over the course of an hour all of these things gradually went away, beginning with the vertical lines and ending with the screen flicker.

This problem then reoccurred today. Interestingly enough, it was again a Discord screen that was "burned in." I tried the same things today, and what I noticed was that the "burned in" part persisted even after my computer was turned off. I double checked this by turning my computer on, to make sure that the screen was still "burned in." I then turned off my computer and my monitor, unplugged my monitor's power and HDMI cables, plugged my monitor's power cable back in and turned it on. I could still see the "burned in" Discord screen, again focused around the edges.

The way I see it, my monitor is probably broken. The reasons for this should be fairly obvious. However, I am not 100% sure. **Is it possible for a problem with the graphics card, driver, or even the OS to cause this kind of behavior?**

A few notes:

1. All of the behavior above was much more clearly visible on dark but not black screens. I could not see any of this on a black screen.
2. I'm not certain that the operating system is even relevant. The problem never occurred on Windows, even though I have been using Ubuntu about 95% of the time over the last few weeks and so a new problem in this time would have likely shown up in Ubuntu anyway.
3. I am also not sure it's even related to Discord. I use Discord enough for this not to be incredibly unlikely, but also not enough for this to be considered probable. However, the Discord app is mostly a shade of dark grey which seems to be the shade which responds most strongly to the issues I mentioned above.
4. If anyone needs more information about my software, graphics driver, etc. just let me know what you need and what the best way is for me to find it.
5. I have the hardware acceleration option turned off on Discord.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem but on Windows with AMD graphics card. Also extremely Discord related. Viewing an image sent over Discord causes it to leave behind a ghost image for about 1h like you said. Restarting pc doesn't even take it away! Eventually it does go away though.

Answer (score 0):

> what I noticed was that the "burned in" part persisted even after my
> computer was turned off.
>
> Is it possible for a problem with the graphics card, driver, or even
> the OS to cause this kind of behavior?

NO

The screen is bad.

Comment: Replacing the screen did not fix the issue (forgot to update the question), but an update to Ubuntu since then has

Comment: @DreamConspiracy if the information you provided was accurate, and the image on your screen “persisted after it was turned off,” then I am sorry to say that it is beyond impossible that a Ubuntu update solved the issue. However, thank you for updating the thread.

Comment: maybe it was a graphics driver update that shipped with a Ubuntu update. I'm just stating what I observed

Answer (score -1):

Discord is dangerously prone to burn in and ghost images, to this day. PC and mobile versions both, and very few measures have been taken to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you edit this answer in order to explain it with more detail?